# Animation stop and starting without just going smoothly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my animation not to jagger it goes up turns waits a seconds it doesn't just go smoothly I tried changing the left: and rotate: but it didn't change the stopping and starting the droplet just goes up stops turns starts moving stops turns starts moving stops turns I tried to swap sections change the %

```css
.drop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 46%;
  background: #7cc1ff;
  border-radius: 0% 100% 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.drop {
  animation: fall 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 35%;
    left: 46%;
  }
  10% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  20% {
    top: 15%;
    left: 60%;
  }
  30% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 70%;
    rotate: 100deg;
  }
  40% {
    top: 30%;
    left: 80%;
    rotate: 190deg;
  }
  50% {
    top: 60%;
    left: 80%;
  }
  60% {
    top: 70%;
    left: 80%;
  }
  70% {
    top: 80%;
    left: 80%;
  }
  80% {
    top: 100%;
    left: 80%;
  }
  90% {
    top: 100;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 80%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 46%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<div class="drop"></div>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to adjust the `animation-timing-function`. Set it to linear (its default is `ease`, which will accelerate and decelerate at each keyframe)

Comment: You mean at the end of the animation? Or when pausing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Linear Works try

```
Animation: linear Anim 4s;
```

instead of

```
Animation: Anim 4s;
```